# Follwing the "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987505/how-do-i-decompress-a-dsn6-file-into-a-readable-format" to extract electron density data

Tags: binary, ascii, pdb

```
`import sys`
`from importlib import reload
`import struct
`import numpy as np``
`reload(sys)`
`#sys.setdefaultencoding('Cp1252')`
`#sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`
`#Type = sys.getfilesystemencoding()`
`file_path = r'cbs_2fofc.dsn6'`
`def read_dsn6_file(file_path):``
    `with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:`
        `# Read the header information`
        `header = f.read(512).decode('ASCII')`
        `nx, ny, nz = map(int, header.split()[1:4])`

        `# Read the electron density data`
        `data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int8)
    `# Reshape the data array to match the dimensions`
    `data = np.reshape(data, (nx, ny, nz))`

    `return data`
`
`# Example usage`
`file_path = '/data/home/moradi/cbs_2fofc.dsn6'`
`electron_density_data = read_dsn6_file(file_path)`

`# Accessing specific values in the electron density data`
`x = 10  # x-coordinate`
`y = 20  # y-coordinate`
`z = 30  # z-coordinate`

`value = electron_density_data[x][y][z]`
`print(f"Electron density at ({x}, {y}, {z}): {value}")``
```

#`Following the  question in this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987505/how-do-i-decompress-a-#`dsn6-file-into-a-readable-format `#`I wish to extract the  electron density data but I have faced with following error: `#`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

## `I have check for some solution  with no success.`

#sys.setdefaultencoding('Cp1252')
#sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
#Type = sys.getfilesystemencoding()`